# Data Migration 2 Tables with some similar rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables which has been archived. They has same rows for a single date with few data.
I need to insert table 2 record into table 1 . When I do I ll get unique constraint ignored error. How to achieve it. Is there any hints to ignore already existing data and just insert new records.

Comment: Please show us sample data for both tables and expected results. Also specify what are the existing contraints on the tables.

Comment: You may want to use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`. Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F

Comment: Or: `insert into t1 select * from t2 where id not in (select id from t1)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.The main thing is table 1 has 100 million records. Will it be faster when use merge or not exists(join) method ?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this:**

```
INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.Field1=destTable.Field1 and
                       SrcTable.Field2=DestTable.Field2...etc.)
                 )
```

Comment: @Jey . . . `NOT EXISTS` is more appropriate than `MINUS`, because you can remove only the columns specified in the unique constraint.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And what about `NOT EXISTS` vs. `MERGE`? @Jey asked in the comment section under the question, but I'm also intrested....

Comment: @dmak2709 . . . The two are functionally equivalent.  I tend to prefer `not exists` because the syntax is standard, whereas `merge` is not supported by al databases and has some syntax variation in those that do support it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, so no difference in performance neither?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SET` operator `MINUS` to achieve the result as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (<COLUMN NAMES>)
SELECT <COLUMN NAMES> FROM TABLE2
MINUS
SELECT <COLUMN NAMES> FROM TABLE1
```

Description of the `MINUS` operator as per the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators005.htm) is

> All distinct rows selected by the first query but not the second

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `MERGE`, on the following [link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-merge/) you can find a useful tutorial which explains it in detail.

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
    USING table2 b ON (a.col1 = b.col1) -- define your own search condition
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 ...)
            VALUES (b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 ...);
```